# Using ioctl to change value of autorepeat

Tags: c, kernel, drivers, ioctl

How can I use ioctl to change the value of auto-repeat for a given device in C?

I know about

```
#define REP_DELAY               0x00
#define REP_PERIOD              0x01
```

source: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L931

I didn't find any tutorial or documentation about these things.
This question is not vague, it is actually just about using ioctl with REP_DELAY and REP_PERIOD.
How can I use them with ioctl?

Comment: You could find the source for the [`kbdrate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/kbdrate.8.html) command and see how it does it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks but isn't there some way to do it with REP_DELAY and REP_PERIOD?

Comment: I don't know, but if you read the source for the command it might tell you a way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the file descriptor for that particular device. 
The request is

```
#define KDKBDREP        0x4B52
```

The parameters to pass are

```
 struct kbd_repeat {
        int delay;      
        int period;     
 }
```

Source http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/kd.h?v=3.10#L153 .

Comment: Well it is not changing anything for me. struct kbd_repeat rep;
 rep.delay = 0;
 rep.period = 100;
 ioctl(fd, KDKBDREP, rep);

Answer (score 1):

I think the ioctls you need are `EVIOCGREP` and `EVIOCSREP`. I can't find any documentation for them, but they are declared [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L102) as working on `unsigned int[2]` so I guess that `REP_DELAY` and `REP_PERIOD` are indexes in that array.

Something like this should work:

```
unsigned int rep[2];
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGREP, rep); /* get current values */
/* do something with rep[REP_DELAY] and/or rep[REP_PERIOD] */
ioctl(fd, EVIOCSREP, rep) /* write new values */
```

The `KD` ioctls predate evdev so the `REP_` macros aren't be used with them. If you're operating directly on a virtual console (`/dev/tty1` etc.) then `KD` and `struct kbd_repeat` are the way to go. On the newer input devices, `EVIOC` and `REP_`.